# How to dynamically scale the screen where the style 'position: absolute' applied components is placed based on resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I scale the screen **dynamically** based on resolution when the code looks like this?

```css
.drawing-board {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.drawing-board .box-1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
  top: 90px;
}

.drawing-board .box-2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lime;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="drawing-board">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any simple examples for this case?

Comment: Use `vh` & `vw` for viewport height and width respectively.

Comment: If the width and height of a component must be specified in pixels, is there a way to scale the screen? For example, using media queries...